# How can I use head in place of struct node?

Tags: c, data-structures

I made a function to create a node in a linked list which takes an integer as argument. My program is running fine when I am using this function, but my doubt is in the use of `malloc` here.

What I have tried:

My structure is:

```
struct{
    int data;
    struct node*
}
```

This is my insert function:

```
void insert(int x){
    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data=x; 
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
}
```

Note that I declared head as a global variable as:

```
struct node* head;
```

Clearly head is a pointer variable (pointer to the struct node) which will take up only 4 bytes in memory, whereas (struct node) will take up 8 bytes in memory.
My doubt is this: when I am using head in sizeof operator instead of struct node, that is

```
struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(head));
```

I am getting no error, no warning, and getting the exact same answer as I was before, but the memory allocation will be different for head (4 bytes containing an address in the form of an integer) and struct node (8 bytes), so shouldn't it affect my program?

Comment: You'll be invoking *undefined behavior* if you don't allocate enough memory for a `struct node` - so anything can happen in your program

Comment: As written, your structure does not compile. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as well as the problem you're having, so that we can help diagnose what's going wrong.

Comment: The structure you show refers to a `struct node` type that you don't show.  That will cause confusion, sooner rather than later, probably requiring casts that should be unnecessary.

Comment: Should be `struct node *temp = malloc(sizeof *head);`. I think this is an argument why you shouldn't cast the value of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can and you will run into problems. Since C does not do any boundary checking for you, you are only getting an illusion of it working correctly. You are just getting lucky that no one else is using the piece of memory you are accessing in your *next pointer. So, it may not may not work if you try this code on a different machine or on the same machine a few mins/hrs later. You are essentially corrupting the memory here by writing over a piece of memory which you have not malloc'ed.